# Which solitaire game is this?

Tags: identify-this-game, solitaire

This game may not actually **be** an actual *solitaire*, as it might have been something my grandmother had me do when I was wee to keep me out of her hair.  But if anyone DOES know it, I would dearly like to know if I am forgetting some of the rules or playing it wrong.

**Play**: using standard 52 card deck, deal 4 cards, one into each of 4 piles.  If some of the cards have the same rank then move the matching cards to the rightmost, repeating for all matches.  Then deal another 4 cards, one onto each stack, and repeat.  If all 4 on top of a stack are the same card (four of a kind) you withdraw them from the deck entirely. You repeat until you have no more cards.

**For example**, if you dealt A 2 3 4, nothing would move.  If you dealt 2 3 3 4 on top of that, the left 3 would move onto the right three.  This would reveal the 2 that it had covered, and the 2 on top of the leftmost stack would shift to the right.

Once all cards are dealt, you pick them back up in sequence (This is the part I remember the least.  I THINK that the leftmost pile ends up on the 'bottom' of the new stack, and the rightmost pile on the top) and then deal through again until you win.

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is very similar to a game called "[Perpetual Motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perpetual_Motion_(solitaire))" -- the rules from Wikipedia specify gathering same-ranked cards to the left, and only allow for eliminating groups of cards if the four of a rank are dealt out to the four piles as part of a single deal.  They seem similarly unclear as to which pile should end up on top of the new stack.

Comment: I don't get the impression that they are "unclear" as to which pile should end up on top.  I think they imply that it doesn't matter, as long as you are consistent.

Comment: see this analysis for the game  https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0907/0907.1955.pdf