# What card game is this, my mom taught me

Tags: identify-this-game, solitaire

It’s a single player game, where you place a card face up and continue dealing the cards one by one. The goal is to get the entire deck in one stack. As you deal the cards you match by suit or number and you can only skip 3 places to add to a stack. Thank you in advance:)

Comment: Sounds like it could be the same as either [this](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/15435/what-is-the-name-of-this-solitaire-card-game) or [this](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/35524/which-solitaire-game-is-this), but hard to tell from your description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like Accordion to me.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accordion_(card_game)

Comment: Yes this is it!!!  thanks so much!